# Select rows with second minimum rank in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, minimum

I have a table with customer numbers, order numbers & rank fields. Each customer number can have multiple orders with different rank values. Ex.

```
cust#  order#  rank

1       12      1
1       13      3
1       14      2
2       15      2
2       16      1
3       17      3
3       18      4
3       19      1
3       20      2
```

I am using this table to populate another table which looks like this.

```
cust   order1 order2 order3 order4
1       12      14     13
2       16      15
3       19      20     17    18
```

So, how do I select the second, third minimum rank to populate the `order2, order3, order4` fields?

EDIT: I do not want to do by ranks 1,2,3 etc because sometimes there might be no rank 2 so the order2 field will be empty but order3 field will be populated. I want to do by minimum rank. 1st minimum rank in order1, second minimum rank in order2 etc.

Comment: After your edit I updated my answer. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a combination of `ROW_NUMBER()` and `PIVOT`, like this:

```
DECLARE @tmp TABLE (Customer INT, OrderNumber INT, Ranking INT)
INSERT INTO @tmp (Customer, OrderNumber, Ranking)
SELECT 1,       12,      1 UNION
SELECT 1,       13,      3 UNION
--SELECT 1,       14,      2 UNION
SELECT 2,       15,      2 UNION
SELECT 2,       16,      1 UNION
SELECT 3,       17,      3 UNION
SELECT 3,       18,      4 UNION
SELECT 3,       19,      1 UNION
SELECT 3,      20,      2


SELECT 
    Customer, 
    MAX(Order1) AS Order1, 
    MAX(Order2) AS Order2, 
    MAX(Order3) AS Order3, 
    MAX(Order4) AS Order4
FROM 
  (
    SELECT 
        *, 
        'Order' + CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Customer ORDER BY Ranking) AS VARCHAR(4)) AS rn 
    FROM @tmp 
  ) d
PIVOT 
  (
    MAX(OrderNumber) FOR rn IN ([Order1], [Order2], [Order3], [Order4])
  ) p
GROUP BY Customer
```

Comment: I like your idea of doing a Rank over the Rank field itself. It is a masterstroke.

Comment: Glad to help!  If this solves your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT R1.cust#, R1.order#, R2.order#, r3.order#, r4.order#
FROM MyTable AS R1
LEFT JOIN MyTable AS R2 ON R1.cust# = R2.cust# AND R2.rank = 2
LEFT JOIN MyTable AS R3 ON R1.cust# = R3.cust# AND R3.rank = 3
LEFT JOIN MyTable AS R4 ON R1.cust# = R4.cust# AND R4.rank = 4
WHERE R1.rank = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this helps:

```
SELECT cust#,
       MAX(CASE WHEN rank = 1 THEN order# END) AS order1,
       MAX(CASE WHEN rank = 2 THEN order# END) AS order2,
       MAX(CASE WHEN rank = 3 THEN order# END) AS order3,
       MAX(CASE WHEN rank = 4 THEN order# END) AS order4     
  FROM(SELECT cust#,
              order#,
              ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY cust# ORDER BY order#) rank
         FROM your_table
      )
 GROUP
    by cust#
```